# Return type with property with same name as parameter value

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have a function like this:

```
function refactorQueryResult<D, E>(
  name: string,
  original: UseQueryResult<D, E>
) {
  return {
    [name]: original.data,
    [`${name}UpdatedAt`]: original.dataUpdatedAt,
    [`${name}Error`]: original.error,
    [`${name}ErrorUpdatedAt`]: original.errorUpdatedAt,
    [`${name}FailureCount`]: original.failureCount,
    [`${name}HasError`]: original.isError,
    [`${name}Fetched`]: original.isFetched,
    [`${name}FetchedAfterMount`]: original.isFetchedAfterMount,
    [`${name}Fetching`]: original.isFetching,
    [`${name}Idle`]: original.isIdle,
    [`${name}Loading`]: original.isLoading,
    [`${name}HasLoadingError`]: original.isLoadingError,
    [`${name}IsPlaceholder`]: original.isPlaceholderData,
    [`${name}IsPrevious`]: original.isPreviousData,
    [`${name}HasRefetchError`]: original.isRefetchError,
    [`${name}Refetching`]: original.isRefetching,
    [`${name}HasSuccess`]: original.isSuccess,
    [`${name}IsStale`]: original.isStale,
    [`fetch${name[0].toUpperCase()}${name.slice(1)}`]: original.refetch,
    [`remove${name[0].toUpperCase()}${name.slice(1)}`]: original.remove,
    [`${name}Status`]: original.status,
  };
}
```

But to my dismay, when I use the result:

```
const { cards } = refactorQueryResult("cards", useQuery(listCards(filters)))
```

Typescript complains that cards does not exists, but of course it does.

Is there a way to type hint the return value?

Keep in mind I do realize I can just do:

```
const { data: cards, isFetched: cardsFetched /*, etc */ } = useQuery(listCards(filters))
```

But I'm both lazy and curious, so I am wondering if there isn't a way to waste a couple of processor cycles so I have to type less.

For a much simpler function, I've tried:

```
function renameData<D, E>(
  name: string, 
  queryResult: UseQueryResult<D, E>
): { [name]: D } & UseQueryOptions<D, E> {
} & UseQueryResult<D, E> {
  return { [name]: queryResult.data, ...queryResult }
}
```

But here typescript complains: `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type`

I think it is probably not possible without adding another type parameter. So something like:

```
export function refactorQueryResult<T, D, E>(
  name: string,
  original: UseQueryResult<D, E>
): ComplicatedTemplateMapping<T, UseQueryResult<D, E>> {
  // ...
}

// Then elsewhere
const { cards, cardsFetched } = refactorQueryResult<{ cards }>(
  "cards", useQuery(listCards(filters))
)
```

But here I'm not sure how to even begin with the checks and slicing in `ComplicatedTemplateMapping`

Comment: Can we get a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider approach with mapping:

```js
interface UseQueryResult<TData = unknown, TError = unknown> {
  data: TData | undefined;
  dataUpdatedAt: number;
  error: TError | null;
  errorUpdatedAt: number;
  failureCount: number;
  isError: boolean;
}

function refactorQueryResult<D, E, T extends string>(
  name: T,
  original: UseQueryResult<D, E>
): TransformedData<UseQueryResult<D, E>, T> {
  return {
    [name]: original.data,
    [`${name}UpdatedAt`]: original.dataUpdatedAt,
    [`${name}Error`]: original.error,
    [`${name}ErrorUpdatedAt`]: original.errorUpdatedAt,
    [`${name}FailureCount`]: original.failureCount,
    [`${name}HasError`]: original.isError,
  };
}

type MappedData<N extends string> = {
  data: N,
  dataUpdatedAt: `${N}UpdatedAt`,
  error: `${N}Error`,
  errorUpdatedAt: `${N}ErrorUpdatedAt`,
  failureCount: `${N}FailureCount`
  isError: `${N}HasError`
}

type TransformedData<QR, N extends string> = {
  [P in keyof QR as P extends keyof MappedData<N> ? MappedData<N>[P] : never]: QR[P]
}

function test(queryResult: UseQueryResult) {
  const {
    test,
    testError,
    testUpdatedAt,
    testErrorUpdatedAt,
    testHasError,
  } = refactorQueryResult("test", queryResult)
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0bPow)

Comment: Ah, ok. That is pretty good actually.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up figuring this one out on my own. It is possible, as it turns out! Typescript is amazing. The trick is to use a third type parameter. But you don't actually need to ever specify it. Typescript will detect it. So whereas the original function signature was:

```
function refactorQueryResult<D, E>(
  name: string,
  original: UseQueryResult<D, E>
)
```

It is now:

```
function refactorQueryResult<D, E, T extends string>(
  name: T,
  original: UseQueryResult<D, E>
): RefactoredQueryResult<UseQueryResult<D, E>, T>
```

Typescript is smart enough to detect that T should equal the string literal passed in as an argument. So it is enough to call:

```
const { test, testFetched } = refactorQueryResult("test", queryResult);
```

It won't work if you provide a string variable instead of a literal as the name parameter. It won't show an error, but the result type will be a generic record. It will work if the type of the varaible is a string literal, and if the variable type is a union of string literals then you will get a key for each possible value of the variable and each key of the original type.

The type itself is defined as follows:

```
type RefactoredQueryResult<QR, N extends string> = {
  [K in keyof QR as K extends `data${infer R}`
    ? `${N}${Capitalize<R>}`
    : K extends `error${string}`
    ? `${N}${Capitalize<K>}`
    : K extends `is${infer R}Error`
    ? `${N}Has${Capitalize<R>}Error`
    : K extends `isSuccess`
    ? `${N}HasSuccess`
    : K extends `is${infer R}Data`
    ? `${N}Is${R}`
    : K extends `isStale`
    ? `${N}IsStale`
    : K extends `is${infer R}`
    ? `${N}${R}`
    : K extends `refetch` | `remove`
    ? `${K}${Capitalize<N>}`
    : K extends `status`
    ? `${N}Status`
    : never]: QR[K];
};
```

I learned that `infer` is pretty much the type equivalent of slice, though it could have been avoided completely with a more explicit type. There doesn't seem to be the same kind of limit applied to conditionals as there are for union types. So in fact I'm going with the explicit version in production, but I've provided the shorter version with the `infer` clause here in case it helps someone who has a different use case.

[Here is a playground for this code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGcIEUCu0CeAShOjgDZgA8AKgCJxhzIC8yOIA1iAPYDuIAGmTUAolCjcoLNpx78AfMgDeAWABQyTcgAmDOAC5h9RsgA+M7RBigI2gNzqtOvagAOuyNoCCYQyBwAtgBG0A4aWtASUIai4pJmyP5kZGFOkZJuHrY+foEhUKla8MBkOFAQAMLc7L6JeaGOWsDoYlGGQdzcZBBwIIWazQBiEGAIABa27Z3dvf3IQyPj2TCQUACy1eBTXT19jQPow6NjoADm2zN74QcAktrdF7tzzQAy3HDaZ4+z+-Pobx8zq1JN8rk5mgAFMiICBjLqWKDGAzIDo7H7XP4Q8oAN2A1XQSNBz3QxBgizGwOiKOmT1+zVJ5K+1LRYKa6AAyowHszLsT2TgEEh0Ogib9ymTjoYABQAShYimx3GA9jFEAC3GxEGlcuYCqVKox6EYYBwIuQAHJld1zQlzWR3p8QKcbeZzekoC6LaRBSR0OawgBfdTqGDsBBgPEgZDixBgSS4AjEUgUSi0IQiITUZAQAAekBA2nQyCNUDO8iljRAcACWuEAkakmAp1AcDIhgw2DwUCIJHIVDTyBE8nUMsMpNjklsCe7Sb7lA7057yf76fkmcUqnC5RNUCjm6cAG0qzWALqGRvNqtkAB0Hjg9YxB4ABgASJTHiABzIMbJgJ9n5ALxbG872-TwfAfQ9X3fatP0pf9z1LS9W2vd1IK0Z83w-ANKTA38EMApDgNQuIoDw7wwHQzRMJgmsA0GOASjKSpNj-ACgKva9ilKcoqhqKjkBo7CAAk4BaUiCI4lDmkpAShNg+jyVsSSiM4hZjlsOToOwo4lm8FZoA2GoVKbYj1L0rwDPWVitKwhTdJOJ0TOQm9zMc05bNoz87m6ZyzPQHyIE87CAUdU4-LU-4HTOYKFNEqLASdeD2NU6SErC2TfnkuibnQKEYThMgEQitL8qQQqESRWKcrynE8VNErXNqiBcXxKqsu0uKxIZY5ksQ0zIp68ZMsfTq6KG9zGuvekrEZJ1qs-eL+R9YUpuaZahXQBaA1yzlWwgNaOS5IKOvFck7JrA8AAYT2vOM3FcaAKjEiBZQDC6IGvdAyGAJApQARhlAMprO44tPKdVNQ+67bvu1xHqgZ7MDej6vp+v7AeBlKBpQiGNRO0aPoDPaTXQKajQYU10IDQNgzUMB8Ee5Bx3DSdtEXWcUywQghAAOWzPMIALIsSzLaR90EgBpeYow4CB8G4GBkG55AxOQaXc3zQtkAAIjvHXfgAfmQXnfkMDXBeF3XQPcH8KINjFjeg3mv1t8C-zN9WBa1osdfdB2nCdt8Xfgz2LZ93X3XInwA60IOlBD0jo49jFze9oXtZ17jmL48BY80eOXYYpjeNYp8w-Tq2dZk0j8+QQuA3i0PU69zWM99tzbDrhuHOUiu26rzv9NWIy86N5BncUjTh8Msv+8tzO3LObuJ+DqfxjOcuW-D9vdeaQKV8nwKt6cNOB8X9Ll-HyfQs3+eI+ry+ktr6+1-i2-n6iE+tDPheO7y6E5V4TQCRIfNeuUyqwmAVAb+mhf4P0hHVNqegwEJx2s1VqDV7670fhNSkqCXbxTwRJbBg8SSzWOFfR2q80ETTvtvSuF8Nq+gIY3MSzDVqkKYcdVhu1jqwOQPAnBoNxiHxEWMN8z1XDAC5MAAAXhASgvN5DAy4b7PGmoxFqnxpIuA0jZEKKUSogRQiq4U1JqwkmWCW4gBatAAC3MDySxPLTNQIYwwRm4FGSARopQAEcuxLj7O2TAHNewUDlBLBAXijTKF+D4yi8SSBgBGk4BJycBIJNwm7X8mTklN1Inko0vdtBFLACUyyI8bJJOKXNDyNSwCBTKR-epGIEnv2ip-SQZSIGAKgUVaAPSMH1S2g0ohFDhqFIaXQ+aYz2ECk2kMva3QBLiOoMk1Z2jNTrKNGUqxozwgBmkDGVmUAwnLilDrBJOshABMTOEsAMp1BBjUEAA)
It includes a mock of the `UseQueryResult` type and a function that deconstructs a parameter of the refactored type as a sort of test.

Comment: I think it worth creating several type maps instead of nested conditional types